# How to create a generic redirect endpoint with Angular like http://example.com?redirectTo=anothersite.com

Tags: angular, angular11

I'm trying to create a generic redirect endpoint using angular `v11.2.5`, but i'm not sure how to approach this correctly.

Basically i'd like to be able to provide a redirect link to any kind of site in the query params. The user should log in to the site and then get redirected to whatever site is specified in the query params.

For example:

```
http://example.com?redirectTo=http://subDomain.example.com
```

The redirectTo parameter could be any site, but the first use-case would be a subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

I updated Angular `14.2.2` but this should work on all versions;
I made a simple RedirectionComponent:

```html
<div>Redirecting to <a href="{{nextUrl}}">{{nextUrl}}</a></div>
<div *ngIf="message" class="fw-bold text-danger">{{message}}</div>
```

```js
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-redirect',
    templateUrl: './redirect.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./redirect.component.scss']
})
export class RedirectComponent implements OnInit {

    nextUrl: string;
    message: string;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        const nextUrl = <string | null> this.route.snapshot.queryParams?.url;

        if(nextUrl) {
            this.nextUrl = nextUrl;
            if(!this.isUrl(this.nextUrl)) {
                this.message += 'Error, url may be malformed.\r\n';
            }
        } else {
            this.message += 'Error, no url= query parameter found, nothing to redirect to.\r\n';
        }

        this.redirect();
    }

    private redirect(): string | PromiseLike<string> {
        return window.location.href = this.nextUrl;
    }

    private isUrl(string: string) {
        try {
            return Boolean(new URL(string));
        } catch(e){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

It simply grabs the `url` queryParameter, and calls `window.location.href` to open the link in the current window. Its registered as follows:

```js
{
    path: 'redirect',
    component: RedirectComponent,
    canActivate: [
        IsAuthenticatedGuard
    ]
},
```

It is behind the authentication guard so its protected and it makes sure the auth token is set and valid.

In this case the url is a bit different, so it would become `example.com/redirect?url=` instead of `example.com?url=` but that does not matter to me.